# the number of distinct prime ideals of the ring $\mathbb Q[x]/\langle x^4-1\rangle$.

Tags: ring-theory

The number of distinct prime ideals of the ring $${ \mathbb Q[x]}/{I}$$ where $I$ is the ideal generated by $x^4-1$. its ans. is given $3$. I can't understand how? I know the ans. when in place of $4$ there is a prime number

Answer (score 4):

These are the keys for looking for the ideals directly:

1. $\Bbb Q[x]$ is a principal ideal domain, and so the ideals above $(x^4-1)$ are those generated by divisors of $x^4-1$. Since $x^4-1=(x^2+1)(x-1)(x+1)$ is a complete factorization, you can read all divisors from it (and hence see all the ideals above $I$).
2. The quotient $\Bbb Q[x]/I$ for $I\neq 0$ has finite $\Bbb Q$ dimension (equal to the degree of a polynomial generating $I$). That means it's an Artinian ring, so all the prime ideals are maximal.
3. By correspondence, the maximal ideals of the quotient are the maximal ideals of $\Bbb Q[x]$ containing $I$.
4. In principal ideal domains, the maximal ideals are the ones generated by nonzero irreducible polynomials.
5. Combining these points, can you now see which prime ideals contain $(x^4-1)$?

---

Alternatively, you can apply the Chinese remainder theorem, if you know it. It says that (with $I_1=(x^2+1)$, $I_2=(x+1)$ $I_3=(x-1)$) since the $I_j$ are all pairwise comaximal, $\Bbb Q[x]/I=\Bbb Q[x]/(I_1\cap I_2\cap I_3)\cong (\Bbb Q[x]/I_1)\oplus (\Bbb Q[x]/I_2)\oplus (\Bbb Q[x]/I_3)$. The first quotient is isomorphic to $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-1})$ and the other two are isomorphic to $\Bbb Q$. So, this is a product of three fields.

This is again Artinian, so searching for the prime ideals is searching for the maximal ideals. Luckily, the maximal ideals of a product of rings are easy to find: They are of the form $\prod I_i$ where each $I_i=R_i$ except exactly one $j$ where $I_j$ is a maximal ideal of $R_j$.

Answer (score 1):

Have you proved the isomorphism theorems? Do you know the Krull dimension of a quotient ring? Do you know the sum of two comaximal ideals is the entire ideal? Have you factored the equation?

Comment: yes i know isomorphisims thms. but don't know about Krull dim.

Comment: @abc That should help limit the options. It follows from the isomorphism theorems' proofs.

Comment: yes i know know the sum of two comaximal ideals is the entire ideal.please tell me about this ques.

Comment: I still can't understand

Comment: These are the reasons the question should be simple to answer. What is the image of a prime ideal under the quotient, according to the isomorphism theorems? Is it prime? If an ideal $P$ is a prime of the quotient ring, is the ideal $I+P$ of the original ring, $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: I still can't understand

Comment: That's okay. So, the quotient ring's ideals are just the ideals containing it. Also, the Krull dimension of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is 1, so the quotient's Krull dimension is at most 1. If it were 0, the ideal would be maximal, but it's not. Out of the prime ideals, only maximal ideals can contain $x^4-1$ - no others exist. An ideal of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is maximal iff it's generated by an irreducible polynomial (meaning with rational roots). It must therefore be a product of any such polynomials whose ideals contain it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10721/discussion-between-abc-and-loki-clock)

Comment: @abc Sure thing.